# WIX Installer: Major Upgrade Permission Issue

Tags: wix, wix3

I currently use WIX (latest version) to package and bootstrap my Windows Form application.

I'm having an issue where my clients (using SOE workstations in a secure, enterprise environment) don't seem to have access to the MSI package cache directory when using the installer to perform a major upgrade. The installer completes successfully, but when they double click the desktop shortcut to launch the software, it displays the following two wix-generated dialogs:

[image: screenshot]

I then get a 'Fatal error during installation.' message and the software won't open until it is completely uninstalled and reinstalled.

There are no issues at all with a fresh install. The current workaround is to manually uninstall old versions before installing the latest version.

I'm having trouble replicating this problem in my dev/test environments, and requesting my client to change their SOE configuration is out of the question.

Any advice would be most appreciated. I'm hoping there is a way to redirect the cache location to a UserData folder, or an entirely different approach to handling upgrades.

Thanks in advance for any guidance.